# Number or triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $2^a - 5^b*7^c =1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$$\large 2^a - 5^b7^c =1 $$

How many possible triples $(a,b,c)$ are possible?

I tried solving this modulo $5$ but that didn't help. Suggestions?

Comment: Well, I see $(3,0,1)$.  I think $b$ has to be $0$.  I don't think there's a way to make $2^a-1$ a multiple of $5$ without also making it a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If $5|2^a-1$ then $4|a$ and hence $2^4-1|2^a-1$. Thus

$$3| 2^a-1=5^b7^c \,.$$

To complete the proof, you need to see solve the case $a=0$, which yields

$$2^a=7^c+1 \,.$$

$a=3$ is clearly a solution, and you show that there is no other one. [Mihailescu Theorem would prove this, but it is overkill].

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $m|n$ you use here. Could you either elaborate or include a link to a wikipedia page or something?

Comment: Does $m|n$ mean m divides n? Then I think I got it.

Comment: @Sabyasachi yes.

Answer (score 1):

This might be only an insight. Can we count (assuming finiteness) solutions to diophantine equation $2^m=35n+1$ (or equivalently $35k=1 \mod2$)? then the answer should be highly relevant to the triple $(a,b,c)$ of the given equation.

Comment: It doesn't __necessarily__ have to be 35 though. 5 and 7 are valid separately. But those edge cases can be checked manually.

Comment: I thought we are looking at $a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}$. Well if assume they all are positive then since $2^n-1=5^b 7^c$ we should have $2^n-1|5$and $2^n-1|7$.

Comment: I think it doesn't have to be 5 _and_ 7 together. For instance a=3,b=0,c=1 is perfectly valid, but in that case, $2^3$ is not $35n+1$

Comment: I excluded that case by restricting to $\mathbb{N}$. You know that if $a|c$ and $b|c$ provided $(a,b)=1$ corpime then $ab|c$

Comment: Oh. Yes I missed you mentioning N here. I think I need to get some sleep. It's 4.30 in the morning here.